# CSS webkit-sticky invalid property in devtools

Tags: html, css, sass, webview, responsive-design

I have a webpage that is used for webview in both android and ios. I am using the class `-webkit-sticky` for the graph to be stick in place while scrolling. But unfortunately it only works for chrome responsive or android tab. But when i select ipad in device selector in chrome devtools, It does not work. And also I noticed that `-webkit-sticky` is invalid.

[image]

my styles

```
.summary-content {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  /* height: calc(100vh - 50px); */
 overflow-y: scroll !important;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: -webkit-sticky;
 position: sticky;
 align-self: center;
 top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with previous answer. It appears as invalid because this property is for Safari browser and you are probably using some other browser which follows the position: sticky; property. You will need to use both for both Chrome/FF/Safari compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

It's invalid/being overridden by the second position element you have declared. Try removing the second position property, to look like below:

```
.summary-content {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  /* height: calc(100vh - 50px); */
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  align-self: center;
  top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: still the same sir.